# How to specify classes'length in ggplot Histograms?

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics

I work on a data and I have 2 variables like those one:

```
 AgeC        NbSin2003(NbClaim)
[39.5,47.5)     0
[39.5,47.5)     1
[51.5,58.5)     0
[20,27.5)       0
[39.5,47.5)     0
[27.5,33.5)     0
[51.5,58.5)     0
[39.5,47.5)     1
[36.5,39.5)     0
[39.5,47.5)     1
[39.5,47.5)     0
[20,27.5)       0
[39.5,47.5)     0
[51.5,58.5)     0
[51.5,58.5)     0
[51.5,58.5)     0
[27.5,33.5)     0
[58.5,69)       0
```

Now using ggplot I want to have an histogram with NbSin2003 in fonction of AgeC and in any class of AgeC I want to get the average of NbSin2003 corresponding 
values.

*Example:*

If we take the class [39.5,47.5) for AgeC, we will have:

```
AgeC        NbSin2003
[39.5,47.5)     0
[39.5,47.5)     1
[39.5,47.5) 0
[39.5,47.5) 1
[39.5,47.5) 1
[39.5,47.5) 0   
[39.5,47.5) 0
```

For this class, the bar of the histogram will length (0+1+0+1+1+0+0)/7=0.42

I succeeded to do it with barplot and xtabs like that:
`barplot(xtabs(NbSin2003/sum(NbSin2003)~AgeC,data))`

But I want to use ggplot to get a better quality of the histogram and I have done all my graphics using it.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand your question. The solution you provide using `barplot` is not doing what you say you wish to accomplish...  (it returns "1" for the "[39.5,47.5)" level, not 0.42 as you suggest).

Assuming you wish the height of the bar to represent the average of each level in your "AgeC"-factor, here's one way to do it:

```
library (dplyr)
data %>% 
  group_by(AgeC) %>% 
  summarise(avg = sum(NbSin2003) / n()) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = AgeC, y = avg)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

The first two calls groups by level in the "AgeC"-factor, then calculates the average of each level (as you did you your example). The resulting data is then piped into ggplot.

Comment: Or just `mean(NbSin2003)`. You can also use `geom_col()` instead of `geom_bar(stat = "identity")`